# Graph KNN decision boundaries for data with 2+ features

Tags: python, matplotlib, scikit-learn

I am currently learning ML and I am using a KNN classifier to predict the type of beer. The input consists of 8 features. I want to somehow plot each two features in a 2d graph and show the "flattened" decision boundaries using matplotlib. I am using Python with SciKit-Learn.

This is model creation:

```
from sklearn.neighbors import KNeighborsClassifier
neigh = KNeighborsClassifier(n_neighbors=5)
n = neigh.fit(train_x_prepared, train_y["style"])`
```

Where train_x_prepared shape is 124,8 and train_y is a single column dataframe

Comment: You can go through this tutorial: https://cs231n.github.io/neural-networks-case-study/. It contains a demo code for plotting the decision boundary of toy neural networks in a plane. You can adapt it by changing the network by your `KNN` model and the data by taking whichever 2 columns you choose and all the rows.

Comment: This is still using a dataset with 2 columns. There are plenty of examples there. I have 8 columns in my data and want something where they show how to plot decision boundaries flattened.

Comment: By `flattened`, do you mean the high dimensional decision boundary projected to a lower dimensional or 2D plane? If not, can you please clarify what exactly do you mean by `I want to somehow plot each two features in a 2d graph and show the "flattened" decision boundaries using matplotlib.`?

Comment: Yes, that is what I meant. My data has 8 features and I want to train the model on them then project the decision boundaries on 2d plots for each 2 features. But the example you gave uses a dataset with 2 features

Comment: You can't plot n-dimensions on a plane. Reduce your data to 2 dimensions by PCA  e.g. and you're well to go

Comment: I tried that, but even with 3 features after pca, the performance drops by half (96% to 45%). I want to plot an n dimensional plot then project it on several 2d plots